# Installation of Jenkins in AWS EC2 Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins

I am trying to implement the CI/CD pipeline for my spring boot application deployment using Jenkins on AWS EC2 machine. And I am using containerized deployment of micro services using Docker. When I am exploring about the installation of Jenkins I found that , we can use Jenkins docker image. And also we can install normally. I found the following link for example of normal installation of Jenkins.

```
wget -q -O — https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

Here my confusion is that , If I am using Dockerized deployment of my micro services , Can I use normal installation of Jenkins in my VM and Can I use docker commands inside Jenkins pipeline job?

Can anyone help me to clarify the confusion please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run docker commands in Jenkins pipelines on the same machine where Jenkins exists you should run it without container as that configuration will be much easier for you - you need to just add Jenkins to "docker" group so he can run docker containers.

When you run Jenkins from within container configuration is a little harder as probably you need to map host's docker daemon socket to Jenkins container so he can start docker containers on host or you need to use docker-in-docker feature but please take a look on that article: http://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/

Comment: Thank you mr. Jakub for your response. I understood .But when I explored Jenkins with kubernetes , almost all documentations are showing run the Jenkins within the kubernetes cluster. Since here I will use Ansible and Kubernetes later. But now I am only trying to implement one sample. These are the things making me confusing. I hope that you got my actual confusion ?

Comment: Kubernetes is a little different story as when you run Jenkins on Kubernetes you can configure Jenkins to use Kubernetes API so Jenkins doesn't start container directly - he just says to Kubernetes: hey! please deploy for me X and Y so Kubernetes will run docker commands "underhood"